# How to simply inherit all Olivero regions into my sub-theme?

Tags: theming

I am trying to create a subtheme for the Olivero default theme.

My problem is that not all Olivero regions are inherited into the sub-theme.
For example, some of the regions that are missing are "Content Above" and "Content Below".

To create the sub-theme, in `/web/themes` I have added the following files:

### globalrs.info.yml

```yaml
name: globalrs
type: theme
core_version_requirement: ^8 || ^9
description: Global resources
base theme: olivero
libraries:
  - globalrs/resources
```

### globalrs.libraries.yml

```yaml
resources:
  js:
    behavior.js: {}
  css:
    theme:
      style.css: {}
```

How to simply inherit **all** Olivero regions into my sub-theme?

Comment: Regions are not inherited by sub themes, you have to copy the regions from the parent to your theme's `*.info.yml` file, or else the default system themes are used.

Comment: Oh, I see, well, my problem with taking that approach is my fear that the regions I have copied would suddenly become outdated (if Olivero itself would be drasticaly upgraded). That's why I seek some "version agnostic" automatic inheritance instead of declaring region by region by name.

Comment: That basically never happens.

Comment: If you are that concerned you can copy Olivero then customize it as you wish, and not be subject to breaking changes.

Comment: I believe what cilefen describes is exactly why regions are not inherited.

Comment: @cilefen if I copy the entire Olivero would it still be counted as a "sub-theme"?

Comment: I think what I seek is "continuous integration" of the regions of the parent theme to the child theme. By the way, wasn't that the behavior in Drupal 7?

Comment: Again, its extremely rare for themes to add regions out of the blue, especially core themes. This really isn't a problem.